# Getting the color of the element at mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is it possible to get the color of an element at the position of the mouse cursor programmatically?

It's not as simple as simply doing a css check for the background-color, as there could be color gradients or z-index complications, etc..

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How can I get the color of any specified pixel on a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202476/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-any-specified-pixel-on-a-web-page)

Comment: So you don't miss it, I just added a new answer to the question Guillaume linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19480073/1276321